# How to show <div> as responsive drop down list using bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, styles, angular-ui-bootstrap

show `<div>` list as responsive **drop down** list under ***second textbox*** from the give JsFiddle using bootstrap

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3etbtfwL/328)

I have two textbox with Col-xs-6. In that I want output like this image

[image]

Comment: can you explain more about what you want, is text box used for auto search in your drop down options?

Comment: your question has very low quality details :/

Comment: @Maher Instead of saying something like that, please try to give helpful and instructive comments.

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, and very broad. I suggest you read the [ask] page, and take the [tour]. I'm sure you'll find them useful. The tips and explanations in those pages can help you write a question that others can answer.

Comment: Got solution. Refer this http://jsfiddle.net/3etbtfwL/347/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">orange</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">bnana</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">lemon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">apple</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No luck. I updated question in detail

Answer (score 1):

```
input {
width: 100%;
}
```

Then it will take same width of your list items.

Comment: No luck. I updated question in detail.

Answer (score 1):

In this sample we 2 drop down with bootstrap framework and angularjs which you can change them with click or default value.

```js
var app = angular.module('httpApp', []);

app.controller('httpAppCtrlr', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = ["orange", "banana", "lemon", "apple"]
  $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];


  $scope.onChange = function(item) {
    $scope.selected = item;
  }

  //2
  $scope.selected2 = false;

  $scope.onChange2 = function(item) {
    $scope.selected2 = item;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app='httpApp' ng-controller='httpAppCtrlr'>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{selected}}
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onChange(item)"><a href="#">{{item}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
    {{selected2 ? selected2 : 'select once...'}}  
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="onChange2(item)"><a href="#">{{item}}</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a ng-hide="!selected2" ng-click="selected2 = false">remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No luck. I updated question in detail